# How to Execute FreeSWITCH (fs_cli) from a java application

Tags: java, freeswitch

I am new to freeswitch, I have tried originate command in freeswitch from fs_cli console and it was working properly. now my requirement is to execute the same from a java application.
I have tried following code

```
package org.freeswitch.esl.client.outbound.example;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class Call {
Call() throws IOException {
    Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./fs_cli -x \"originate    loopback/1234/default &bridge(sofia/internal/1789@192.168.0.198)\"");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
    String str = null;
    while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
    System.out.print("success");
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Call call;
    call = new Call();
}
}
```

**Output**

-ERR "originate Command not found!

success

please help me,
fs_cli is at "/usr/local/freeswitch/bin/" location
I have created a symbolic link in my workspace directory.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use the [ESL client](http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Java_ESL)? It should provide much more options, and originating a call would be no problem.

Regarding your particular problem, it looks like your program tried to execute "originate" command in the shell, not the ./fs_cli. Probably it needs more Java documentation reading :)

Comment: Thanks, Can you please suggest me ESL class to originate a call. I found the same above syntax to originate a call even in esl client. please suggest some solution

Comment: I'm not a Java programmer. The FreeSWITCH wiki suggests several ESL client libraries, so you need to dig through them yourself